# How to attach a UIPopover to a CGRect created programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I have a UIPopover that I have created several UITextFields programmatically.  If one of the UITextfields is tapped, I want to have a UIDatePicker inside a UIPopoverController point to the UITextfield that caused the tap.  I am able to get the tag, so I know which CGRect caused the tap; the problem is that I am unable to have the arrow of the UIPopoverController to point to that specific rectangle.

Here is the code (inView: self.frame is incorrect; it's just one of the things I tried)

```
    if(textField.tag == 1301  ) {  //  'startTime' text field

    UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; //ViewController
    UIView *popoverView = [[UIView alloc] init];   //view
    popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    UIDatePicker *datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];//Date picker
    datePicker.frame=CGRectMake(0,44,180,186);  //  180,186
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
    [datePicker setMinuteInterval:15];
    [datePicker setTag:1310];
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(Result) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [popoverView addSubview:datePicker];

    popoverContent.view = popoverView;

    innerPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];

    [innerPopoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(180,206) animated:NO];
    [innerPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(305, -190, 80, 35)  //  WRONG!  TODO
                                       inView:self.frame
                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

}
```

The CGRectMake has the same parameters (x,y,w,h) that the UITextfield was created with.  The error I'm getting is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:]: Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window.'

Is this even possible, having a UIPopover within a UIPopover?

Comment: Pass `self.view` for the `inView:` parameter (assuming `self` is a view controller`. It is also required that `self.view` already be displayed when you present the popover. Read the error. This means the view hasn't been added (presented) yet.

Comment: Build error: Property 'view' not found on object of type 'SubViewData *' (SubViewData is the view controller where the first UIPopover is located)

Comment: You need to pass a `UIView` to the `inView` parameter. It must be the view you want to show the popover from. And the `rect` parameter should be relative to that view.

Comment: That particular UIView would be the one which now displays the first UIPopover... I'm in the method **-textFieldShouldBeginEditing** and all I have is the tag of the rectangle which the user tapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
innerPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];

[innerPopoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(180,206) animated:NO];
[innerPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(305, -190, 80, 35)  //  WRONG!  TODO
                                   inView: SubViewData.view
                      permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

If you have the tag  of a view then do like this:

```
UIView *tappedView=[SubViewData.view viewWithTag:yourTag];

innerPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];

[innerPopoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(180,206) animated:NO];
[innerPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(305, -190, 80, 35)  //  WRONG!  TODO
                                       inView: tappedView.superView
                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Comment: Close, but not it... getting a build error: **Property 'view' not found on object of type 'SubViewData'**

Comment: The 'tag' belongs to the UITextField that is in the first UIPopover, not the view that contains the popover...

Comment: I tried to attach the datePicker to the popoverView, but got this error message, which leads me to believe I can NOT have a popover within a popover... can anybody verify that?   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:]: Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window.'

Comment: No, sorry... it's now outside of the popover, pointing randomly in the popover's parent.  Thank you for your effort; I'm going to try another approach.